# What was the nature of Dobby the Elf?

Tags: character, harry-potter

Dobby appeared frequently in the *Harry Potter* series and

> died in *Deathly Hallows Part 1*

after rescuing Harry and friends.

But in there he mentions that he is a free elf.

If so, why does he save and follow Harry? Who exactly was his master? Why did Bellatrix also say, "How dare you defy your masters?"

Also I assume he did not have any connection with Kreacher, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dobby's *previous* masters were the Malfoys. Harry freed Dobby from them by tricking Lucius into giving Dobby a sock. As Dobby himself said in *Chamber of Secrets*:

> Dobby can only be freed if his master presents him with clothes.

So Dobby considers Harry as his savior and best friend, and owes him a debt. That's different from being *indebted* to him, though. *Dobby has no master* after being freed, but still possesses Elf magic. He helps Harry out of friendship.

Kreacher, on the other hand, *was* Harry's elf, since Harry inherited the House of Black and Kreacher came with it. There is no relation between Dobby and Kreacher, AFAIK, other than both being Elves.

And if you're asking how Dobby found Harry, however...

> He was sent to help him by Aberforth, Dumbledore's brother, who kept an eye on Harry through the shard from Sirius's mirror.

Comment: Ohh yeah when he gave him the sock. By giving a sock to Dobby, he was freed? Is this process of freeing slaves more elaborated in books?

Comment: This was also explained in the movie. I'll add it in.

Comment: You skip the Bellatrix question

Comment: Did I? *Dobby's previous masters were the Malfoys*. Bellatrix thinks the Malfoys own him for life and considers his actions against her sister treason. Since, you know, she's evil and insane and all.